Can't view an ejs file using the a tag to link to it
I am trying to make a blog web app using node.js and express. I am trying to link to ejs files that were created in a blog-files directory using an a tag. I am quite new to programming (2-3 consistent months practice) so I'm finding backend difficult to understand. I should be able to view the files created from within the index.ejs file but it keeps showing an error such as:
Cannot GET /blog-files/2024-04-06_09-22-51.ejs
Index.ejs code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cooper's Blog</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <%- include("form-create.ejs") %>

        <h3>Recent Blog Posts</h3>
        <ul>
            <% files.forEach((file)=> { %>
                <li><a href="/blog-files/<%= file %>">
                        <%=file%>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <% }); %>
        </ul>

</body>

</html>

app.js code
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import fs from "fs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const blogDirectory = "./views/blog-files";
    fs.readdir(blogDirectory, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error reading directory:`, err);
            res.status(500).send("Error reading directory");
            return;
        } else {
            res.render("index.ejs", { files });
        }
    });
});

app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
    //Assign title and content
    const title = req.body["post-title"];
    const content = req.body["post-content"];

    //Assign file content
    let fileContent = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            ${title}
        </title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h3>
            ${title}
        </h3>
        <p>
            ${content}
        </p>
    </body>
    
    </html>`;

    //Generate file name based on current date and time
    const curDate = new Date();
    const fileName = `./views/blog-files/${curDate.getFullYear()}-${(
        curDate.getMonth() + 1
    )
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, "0")}-${curDate
        .getDate()
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, "0")}_${curDate
        .getHours()
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, "0")}-${curDate
        .getMinutes()
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, "0")}-${curDate
        .getSeconds()
        .toString()
        .padStart(2, "0")}.ejs`;

    //Write the file content to an ejs file
    fs.writeFile(fileName, fileContent, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Error writing file: ${err}`);
            res.status(500).send("Error writing file");
            return;
        } else {
            console.log(`File written successfully: ${fileName}`);

            res.render("template.ejs", { title, content });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`);
});


